# Common models for inferring semantics (truth/factuality of statements)?

Tags: natural-language-processing

What are common **models** for creating rules for inferring meanings (e.g. truth values) of natural language statements such as if one wanted to infer the truth value of the input statement

> John Lennon is in Beatles.

which would depend on, whether the model "knew" John Lennon is in Beatles.

Comment: Someone who knows more than me might answer this, but from what I know, this is a *massively* complex field, and probably can't be answered in a single question like this.

Comment: @jmite I'm just looking for some introduction or summary. I was trying to google for it, but there seems to be a plethora of different things and I can't infer, which ones are "entry" kind of ones.

Comment: Some seem to be pointing to database/tables based approach. Which is fairly sensible, because this kind of logic is what SQL is pretty much meant for. I'm wondering though, is there something more to it than SQL. And I'm also wondering about combining SQL with other formal grammar techniques such as context-free grammars.

Comment: One word: [ontologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)). And no, there is no single "model".

Comment: @Bergi But since ontologies seem to form tree-like structures, shouldn't these be feasible to be implemented as context-free languages?

Comment: @mavavilj: No, ontologies are usually represented as some kind of graph

Comment: @Bergi A tree is a form of graph. CFGs usually parse into a syntax tree.

Comment: @mavavilj: Sure, but I mean that most data is non-tree-like